# How to properly bind ItemTemplate's TextBox text to string element of a List?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a List called `Paths` which stores string elements. In MainWindow, I create an ItemControl to display textboxes that should bind to string elements of `Paths`. For example, if `Paths` consists of two string elements `"Hello"` and `"World"`, Main Window should display two textboxes, one displays "Hello" and one displays "World", and the binding should be in TwoWay. So how should I properly do the binding work?

Remarks: I know that I should use ObservableCollection and bind it to ItemControl's ItemSource but I don't know the proper way.

**Main Window**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathsCollection}">>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=?????, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**DataContext**

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private List<string> _paths;
    public List<string> Paths
    {
        get {return _paths;}
        set {_paths = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PathsCollection
    {
        get 
        { // return what????
        }
        set 
        {
        // set what????
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update 1**

The expected effect is shown after I modified the code as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathsCollection,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private List<string> _paths;
    public List<string> Paths
    {
        get {return _paths;}
        set {_paths = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PathsCollection
    {
        get 
        { 
             return new ObservableCollection<string>(Paths);
        }
        set 
        {
             Paths = value.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it just works at the first initialization of the application. It failed to change any string element of `_paths` when I add, remove or modify some text inside `TextBox`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Like Clemens already said, you need to create a `class` which represents you string. So for example you can define that class like:

```
public class PathItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set
        {
            path = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And in your C#-Class you can use that class like:

```
private ObservableCollection<PathItem> pathsCollection;
public ObservableCollection<PathItem> PathsCollection
{
    get { return pathsCollection ?? (pathsCollection = new ObservableCollection<PathItem>()); }
}
```

To add items to this collection you can use:

```
PathsCollection.Add(new PathItem { Path = "MyPath1" });
```

And your xaml than looks like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathsCollection,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This won't work for editing. `{Binding Path=.}` will not replace a string in the source collection. You have to use a collection of items with a string property, which also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: then how to handle ObservableCollection and List together? How to convert them properly?

Comment: @TomFong As shown in the answers to the original questions: `ObservableCollection<StringWrapper>`.

Comment: @Clemens this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: @TomFong You want `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=???? ...}">`. There is no way to do this with a collection of strings.

Comment: @Clemens I use `Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` and succeed but I failed to change element value of the ObservableCollection when I change the text by typing something. I don't know why.

Comment: @TomFong Read the answers to the original questions.

Comment: @Clemens I updated the question so that the question can be clarified.