# Update string element of an ObservableCollection through modifying text in TextBox

Tags: wpf

The problem inherits the problem from the link [How to properly bind ItemTemplate's TextBox text to string element of a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033398/how-to-properly-bind-itemtemplates-textbox-text-to-string-element-of-a-list)

The expected effect is shown at the beginning of the application initialization when the code is as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathsCollection,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    private List<string> _paths;
    public List<string> Paths
    {
        get {return _paths;}
        set {_paths = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PathsCollection
    {
        get 
        { 
             return new ObservableCollection<string>(Paths);
        }
        set 
        {
             Paths = value.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it just works at the first initialization of the application. It failed to change any string element of `_paths` when I add, remove or modify some text inside `TextBox`. Moreover, it did not modify any element of the ObservableCollection `PathsCollection` when I was doing the action. Why?

---

**Update 1**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathsCollection,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```cs
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _paths;
    public List<string> Paths
    {
        get {return _paths;}
        set {_paths = value; InformPropertyChanged("Paths");}
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> PathsCollection
    {
        get 
        { 
             return new ObservableCollection<string>(Paths);
        }
        set 
        {
             Paths = value.ToList();
             InformPropertyChanged("PathsCollection");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void InformPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may be because you are missing to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your model.

Comment: @Aakanksha actually, I have but I didn't write it here.

Comment: Can you write the proper code? Helps to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Issues:

1. This is not working because objects are being updated inside an instance which you are not keeping reference of. The instance that you returned from the `get` below is what gets bound to UI but not tracked in your code:

   ```
       get 
       { 
            return new ObservableCollection<string>(Paths);
       }
   ```

The instance returned from this `get` is getting bound during startup. All the updates are happening inside that bound instance. As you are not keeping reference of this instance in your `SomeClass`, you do not see any change that you have made.

2. Secondly, which is the main reason here: your have collection of strings that is bound to TextBox. Strings in .Net are immutable (i.e. cannot be changed once created). When you change the data in TextBox, a new instance of string is created; but only on UI, not in collection. That's why you don't see that new instance to propagate. Generally, that propagation happens though INotifyPropertyChanged interface, which watches for changes and updates a property. Raw string collection doesn't have a property to be updated, thus it is lost.

To fix this,

1. You have to wire the ObservableCollection back to your list to
   reflect the changes. You also need to retain the instance of
   ObservableCollection in your class.
2. Create container/holder class that will keep your string data. This
   will ensure data gets propagated through property changed event.

Edited version:

```
//This is place holder class to hold state of your string data
public class SomeContainer
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}


public class SomeClass
{
    private List<string> _paths;
    public List<string> Paths
    {
        //This will ensure you return the current list of bound of items.
        get { return PathsCollection.Select(s => s.Path).ToList(); }
        set { _paths = value; }
    }

    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return test;
        }
        set
        {
            test = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SomeContainer> pathsCollection;        

    public ObservableCollection<SomeContainer> PathsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return pathsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            pathsCollection = value;
        }
    }

    //Constructor
    public SomeClass()
    {
        _paths = new List<string>()
        {
            "testing 1", "testing 2"
        };

        var container = _paths.Select(s => new SomeContainer() { Path = s });

        //Initialize
        PathsCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeContainer>(container);
    }
}
```

Xaml Binding

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PathsCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Path}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But the problem is when I modify text in `TextBox`, the elements of  ObservableCollection are not changed correspondingly. I checked this by asserting a Console.WriteLine inside ObservableCollection setter. The setter is not accessed anyway.

Comment: and I keep the `List` because I need this `List` object for some business stuff else

Comment: Give this code a try and test out. I haven't tested/debugged your sample code; issue that I described is just from reading the code.

Comment: tried, and it does not work. The actual problem is any modification of text in `TextBox` does not affect the observable collection (even the setter has not been accessed when I modify some words). I don't know whether the binding is correct.

Comment: See updated code, took a little time to trace it; but in the end is same issue around reference getting lost through immutable string.

Comment: it works! thank you